# Ionic 2 Angular CORS with Sentinment Analysis API

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I am working on a mobile app that can analyze someone's thought by using Aylien Sentiment Analysis API and I am using Ionic 2 Angular 4, I manage to implement the Aylien Sentiment Analysis API to the Ionic but i have this problem, the Cross origin resource sharing (CORS) keeps me from accessing Aylien Sentiment Analysis, i've search about it and im starting to understand the Idea of the CORS but the only thing is that i don't know how to disable the CORS or solve this problem with CORS.

This is my code that i am using to access or to request Aylien's API text analysis

```
var AYLIENTextAPI = require('aylien_textapi');

var textapi = new AYLIENTextAPI({

    application_id: "My ID", 
    application_key: "My Key"
});

textapi.sentiment({'text': 'John is a very good football player!'}, function(error, response) {

    if (error === null) {
        console.log(response);
    }
    else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

And this is the error that gives me

[image]

I have been dealing with this for a while now and I've decided to ask for some help here, thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

CORS has to be handled properly at **server-side**. The 403 forbidden error mentioned that the http options request (preflight) is denied by the server settings. When you not owning the server-side you can only setup a proxy for CORS that handle the requests from your app properly and redirect them to the api (a simple php script would do the trick) but there are many ready to use solutions [out there](https://gist.github.com/jimmywarting/ac1be6ea0297c16c477e17f8fbe51347)

You can't disable CORS. It's a security "feature" from the underlying webview.

Comment: It looks like the AYLIEN server does not support the HTTP `OPTION` type, which is essentially what your browser means with 'preflight'.
AYLIEN returns a HTTP Status 403 whenever you're making an `OPTION` call. Like @fastr.de mentioned, should be a server side change.. :(